# Cannot access docker hub after eval of minikube docker env?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-ingress

I am really confused, I had being learning kubernetes with minikube creating services and other things.

The problem comes in the following shape:

I run the following commands after a fresh install of minikube:

`eval $(minikube docker-env)`

The reason is because I want to get an image from my computer to be used with minikube. My understanding is that with this command I am in the same context for minikube and docker, so I can access my local images. "Please correct me if I am wrong here".

`minikube start`

So I get up and running the cluster, and ready to start creating things.

I want to pull the following container:

`docker pull nginx/nginx-ingress`

Because I want to try an ingress controller to work with my services.

But then I get this weird message:

`Using default tag: latest
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://192.168.99.101:2376. Is the docker daemon running?). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://192.168.99.101:2376. Is the docker daemon running?`

I run:

`docker ps`

And no results with a hang out.

I go to another terminal, I run the `docker ps` and it works like a charm.

Please if someone can bring some light to me of the impact of the command:

`eval $(minikube docker-env)`

And if you know why in my current Term with minikube running cannot access to my docker machine would help a lot.

Comment: Weird enough, I just run again ```eval $(minikube docker-env) ``` and the commands ```pull``` and ```ps``` for docker worked again... but thats not good because now I cannot see the problem that delayed me for 1 hour, any more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`minikube` starts a dedicated virtual machine as a single-node Kubernetes cluster.  If you have other Docker environments (a separate Docker Machine VM, the Docker Toolbox VM, the Docker for Mac or Docker for Windows environments, or a Linux-native Docker) these are separate from the Docker in the VM.  You can't share images or containers between these environments.

If you have private images that aren't published to a registry, you'll have to re-`docker build` them when you switch to the Minikube environment.  You otherwise don't specifically have to `docker pull` things that you're using, when you reference them in a Kubernetes pod spec Kubernetes will pull them for you.

Comment: Yes thats part of the procedure I was doing, rebuilding things inside of the minikube, and avoiding to pull from a registry. I am a bit new to this and kubernetes is a bit overwhelming at first sight to see good practices. Probably I should use a registry and pull things.